# Why explicit boolean checks change behavior of Type guards

Tags: typescript

Why does `item instanceof TypeB === true` behave differently then `item instanceof TypeB` and `isTypeB(item) === true` behave differently then `isTypeB(item)` where `isTypeB(item): item is TypeB;`?

```
const items: (TypeA | TypeB)[] = [];

items.forEach(item => {

  // instanceof explicit
  if (item instanceof TypeB === true) {
    // mouse over item -> TypeA | TypeB
    doWithB(item); // red squiggly
  }

  // instanceof implicit
  if (item instanceof TypeB) {
    // mouse over item -> TypeB
    doWithB(item);
  }

  // Type predicates explicit
  if (isTypeB(item) === true) {
    // mouse over item -> TypeA | TypeB
    doWithB(item); // red squiggly
  }

  // Type predicates implicit
  if (isTypeB(item)) {
    // mouse over item -> TypeB
    doWithB(item);
  }

});
```

This should be the same logic and developer preference. Is this a Typescript bug?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-type-predicates-scope-with-explicit-bool?file=index.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does item instanceof TypeB === true behave differently then item instanceof TypeB

Simply because one is a valid type guard, whereas `=== true` is not a valid type guard. TypeScript doesn't try to be smart as you can *always* break it, e.g. here is a function that returns `true` but changes state internally:

```
  const assign = (): true => {
    item = new TypeA();
    return true;
  }

  // instanceof explicit
  if ((item instanceof TypeB) === assign()) {
    // mouse over item -> TypeA | TypeB 
    doWithB(item); // Aren't you glad its an error
  }
```

Same for `isTypeB(item) === true`.

## More on reporting it

TypeScript could make it valid, but `isTypeB(item)` by itself already works, and a contrived example you want to work, is not going to become an error without justification on why you need to write code like that.

Comment: If "without justification on why you need to write code like that" is referring to the explicit `=== true`, that is hugely debated coding style so you can't call it right or wrong. It is the coding style of members of my team so I want an environment where it is fully supported.